# How can I modify this code to handle an input text with characters as well as integers?

Tags: java, arraylist, parseint

I am trying to take an input .txt file that contains characters as well as integers and reading only the integers so that I can perform calculations. This code works when my input .txt file contains only integers separated by spaces and commas, but fails when I add characters.

Sample File:

```
Student A: 90, 85, 70, 95
Student B: 65, 75, 90, 90
Student C: 80, 80, 75, 85
Student D: 100, 75, 80, 75
```

```
public class test {

    public static void ReadScore (String[] args) {
        List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<>();
        File f = new File("input2.txt"); {
            try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(f)) {
                while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = sc.nextLine();
                    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s*,\\s*");
                    for (String token : tokens) {
                        listIntegers.add(Integer.parseInt(token));
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {System.out.println(listIntegers); }
        }}

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        test.ReadScore(args);
    }
}
```

When the sample .txt file contains only integers, I would receive a result like:

```
[90, 85, 70, 95, 65, 75, 90, 90, 80, 80, 75, 85, 100, 75, 80, 75]
```

However, when the "Student A:" etc is introduced, I'm not sure how to handle that and I receive IOExceptions like:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Jeff: 10"
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
    at test.ReadScore(test.java:17)
    at test.main(test.java:27)
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would be to convert your input file to a complete CSV. Student A, M1, M2..

If you cannot do that, you would have to remove the student name from the input line and then split the string using the delimiter comma.

The pseudo code looks like this
line = line.substring(line.indexOf(':') + 1);

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `java.lang.NumberFormatException` because you are trying to parse Integer from String.
To get only numbers as an output, you need to remove all extra strings other than numbers. Try this:

```
String[] tokens = line.replaceAll("[^0-9,.]", "").split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty clear, you can not convert

> Jeff:10

into an integer....

You can use regex and capture ONLY the numeric part....

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    String n = "Student A: 90, 85, 70, 95";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

this code will print

> 90 85 70 95

something like:

```
    String n = "Student A: 90, 85, 70, 95";
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(n);
    while(m.find()){
        //System.out.println(m.group());
        l.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
    }
    System.out.println("L:" + l);
```